# Visualization using Desktop Power BI, Python and flask

Tags: python, powerbi, flask-restful

I am using flask to create a web api from python functions. My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/store_on_promo_df")
def store_on_promo_df():

    data_df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0)

    is_on_promo_series = data_df['IsPromo'] == True
    data_on_promo_df = data_df.loc[is_on_promo_series]

    return data_on_promo_df
```

Consequently, I would like to have some visualization in Power BI. Therefore, I am using **import data from web** option in power BI.

Problem: I cannot return a dataframe using flask. And I am not sure what to return so that PowerBI reads my data properly.

Finally, please note that this is helpful in my case because I want to share big data with other teams at different location.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Power BI but with a small research, here is how you probably can do it.

Return your data as `JSON` format and look at this [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/) to add your endpoint to Power BI.